# Proof of Corollary 3.51 on Banach Space Theory by Fabian et. al.

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand why Corollary 3.51 in the book *Banach Space Theory* by Fabian et. al. is a consequence of Proposition 3.50.

[image]

I could complete the proof if I could show that: If $\langle E, F \rangle$ is a dual pair then $w(F/G^\perp, G) = \mathcal{T}_{\text{quot}}$ where for quotient topology we impose in $F$ the weak topology $w(F,E)$.

I can proof that $w(F/G^\perp, G)$ is contained in the quotient topology but not the other one.

Any idea of how to complete the missing step in my proof or, maybe even better, how is Corollary 3.51 derived from Proposition 3.50.

I'll also include also the previous page in case is necessary:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This corollary has an error in it. As you can see in the book, the case of subspaces was covered earlier. The corollary should talk about quotients, you can see that from them talking about **closed subspaces** as well proposition 3.50 being about quotient spaces.

To rephrase it, corollary 3.51 says that if $q:E\to E/G$ is the quotient map, where $G\subseteq E$ is a closed subspace of locally convex space $E$, then $q:(E, w)\to (E/G, w)$ and $q:(E, \mu)\to (E/G, \mu)$ where $w$ denotes weak and $\mu$ denotes Mackey topology, are also quotient maps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but could you prove the Corollary? Because I'm really counfused with the mix of all the different topologies.

Comment: @Eparoh I've sketched the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4549005/476484) before, since I used that result myself.

Comment: It is still not clear to me why $\mathcal{M}$ takes that form, for example, in the case of the weak topology. I know that the family of subsets of balanced convex $w(E^*,E)$-closures of finite subsets of $E^*$ generates the weak topology, but I don't see how it is equal to the family of all equicontinuous subsets of $E^*$ with the weak topology.

Comment: @Eparoh This is proposition 3.42 in the same book.

Comment: If two saturated families $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ have the property that $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{T}_\mathcal{G}$ then $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you have a family $\mathcal{F}$ then by taking polars you obtain a system of neighbourhoods of $0$, but if you saturate it, you obtain *all the neighbourhoods of $0$*. The equality $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{T}_\mathcal{G}$ means that if you have $A\in \mathcal{F}$ then $B^\circ\subseteq A^\circ$ for some $B\in\mathcal{G}$. But then from bipolar theorem, $A_0\subseteq B_0$ where $A_0, B_0$ denote the $w(E^*, E)$-closed convex balanced hulls of $A, B$ respectively. Since $\mathcal{G}$ is saturated, $A\in \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now is everything more clear. But, I still have a question. I've seen that $w(G^\perp, E/G) = w^*|_{G^\perp}$ and using that I've proven that, for the case of weak topology, we have that $\mathcal{G} \subset \widehat{\mathcal{M}}$ (where  $\mathcal{G}$ is the saturated family of subsets of balanced convex $w(G^\perp,E/G)$-closures of finite subsets of $G^\perp$). But, how can we prove the other inclusion? I'm having some trouble to prove that inclusion.

Comment: @Eparoh Note that $G^\perp$ is a closed subspace of $E^*$, so that $\text{cl}_{G^\perp}(A) = \text{cl}_{E^*}(A)$ for $A\subseteq G^\perp$.

Comment: Of course I'm talking about $E^*$ with $w^*$ topology. I just wrote it like this so the notation doesn't get messy.

Comment: I knew what you have stated about the closures, but I don't see how it helps. I'll try to explain it better. I want to prove that $\widehat{\mathcal{M}} \subset \mathcal{G}$ with the notation stated before. If $M \in \widehat{\mathcal{M}}$ then $M \in \mathcal{M}$ and $M \subset G^\perp$. As $M \in \mathcal{M}$ we have that there exists a finite set $A$ in $E^*$ such that $M \subset \overline{\text{bco}(A)}^{w^*}$. Now, what we want to achieve is to obtain a finite set $B$ in $G^\perp$ such that $M \subset \overline{\text{bco}(B)}^{w^*}$ (because $w(G^\perp, E/G) = w^*|_{G^\perp}$).

Comment: But, how can we achieve that from knowing only the existence of $A$ (which may not be contained in $G^\perp$) and that $M \subset G^\perp$?

Comment: @Eparoh I see the problem now. I'm sorry, I don't have a solution right now.

Comment: I've managed to solve the case for the Mackey topology (at last!), but I don't see how to solve the problem I've told you for the weak topology. I've you solve it, please let me know.

Comment: I've solved it! I've proven that the weak topology for a dual pair $\langle E, F \rangle$ is also equal to the topology of uniform convergence for the family of all $w(F,E)$-bounded subsets of finite-dimensional subspaces of $F$. Using this family is easy to conclude in the way you intended to do it in the other post.